# Update variable passed to template on change of the model

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have a view `home` as follows:

```
from .models import ExistencePredictions

def home(request):
    context = {
        'latest_prediction': ExistencePredictions.objects.last()
    }
    return render(request, 'detection/home.html', context=context)
```

The problem is that new data is added to `ExistencePredictions` every second or so. Is it possible to update the context of the view every time the model is changed so that the latest data is shown in the template without reloading the page?

Comment: You are looking for the term `ajax` (if you just want to get content from server without reloading, although this way the client would need to periodically keep making requests). Also perhaps this looks like a good place to use [Django Channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Comment: I researched about ajax. But I don't understand how I can check if the model was changed inside the template using Javascript. Can you help? @AbdulAzizBarkat

Comment: You cannot check if the model has changed in the template, as I said above that is just a brute force solution of repeatedly sending requests to the server at regular intervals (Something like using `setInterval` or some similar function). The option of Django Channels that I give perhaps is more suitable for your needs. It uses websockets so your server can itself respond to the client when the model instance has changed.